# GIS Google Maps handle large # polygons add/remove

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am scoping out an application which will be web/mobile based. The application is designed to provide end users with geospatial information. The source of the geospatial data is ESRI Shapefiles. I have a little experience with google maps so I thought about converting these into KML and then parsing that kml file into a database. Some of the core functionality will be as follows

```
+Display 2000 markers with different icons
++have styled info window on this marker
+++ability to add/remove polygons from map related to this marker
+Display ~4000 polygons

Filters
+add/remove markers/polygons based on attribute filters
```

The biggest hurdle I think I will need to overcome is to have this map be both interactive while keeping performance. One piece of functionality is the ability to dynamically add/remove specific polygons. In the past I had rendered large number of polygons via KML files. However since I need to add/remove 1 or 2 polygons from that file at a time I am not sure how I would accomplish that.

Does anyone have any recommendation about how to handle a large number of markers and polygons, with the ability to remove/add polygons one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that many features, you should probably [load your shapefile data into a database](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) like MySQL or [PostGREsql with the PostGIS extension](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_tut01). I'm going to recommend PostGREsql with PostGIS, because you can query your data as [GeoJSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) geometry expressions, which [Google Maps can render right out of the box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), or which you can optionally consume using an [open 3rd-party JavaScript library](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps/blob/master/GeoJSON.js).

Next, you'll want to wire-up the map object so that it loads only data that would appear within the map boundaries---this should keep your map relatively fast. To facilitate this, use the [map object's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Map) "idle" event (fired when the map is finished rendering after a pan or a zoom) to fetch relevant data against the [map object's bounds/extent coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds). Basically, your event handler will make an ajax request to your service layer (PHP, Ruby, C#, etc.) to perform [a spatial query like `ST_Intersects`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html), which will return only the features that within the map area. If your query returns [GeoJSON geometry expressions from the `ST_AsGeoJSON` function](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html), you should be able to push them right into the Google Map with minimal effort.

**SETUP: Example OGR2OGR call** that converts (`-f`) a shapefile into PostGREsql/PostGIS, and translates it (`-t_srs`) to EPSG 4326 (WGS 1984, a.k.a. Longitude/Latitude coordinates). Note that there may be more to this if your data is in an unusual projection.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host=127.0.0.1 user=dbUSERNAME dbname=dbNAME 
password=dbPASSWORD" "C:/path_to/your_data.shp" -nlt GEOMETRY -lco PRECISION=no 
-t_srs EPSG:4326
```

**JavaScript: Example map's "idle" event listener** that catches the idle event and creates a Well Known Text Polygon to use in an ST_Intersects spatial query.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(event)
{
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();

    // Redefine the sw..ne coordinates as a Well Known Text Polygon expression.
    var wkt = encodeURIComponent("POLYGON((" + sw.lng() + " " + sw.lat() + ", " + 
                                                sw.lng() + " " + ne.lat() + ", " +
                                                ne.lng() + " " + ne.lat() + ", " +
                                                ne.lng() + " " + sw.lat() + ", " + 
                                                sw.lng() + " " + sw.lat() + "))");

    // CALL SOME SERVER-SIDE METHOD HERE, SUBMITTING 
    // THE wkt PARAMETER FOR USE IN A SPATIAL QUERY.
    //
    // getGeoJsonData.php?bounds=wkt
});
```

**PHP with PostGREsql/PostGIS: Example PHP script with spatial query** to select any records that fall within your map object's bounds/extent:

```
<?php
// Required input
$ewkt = 'SRID=4326;' . urldecode($_GET["bounds"]);

// Future output
$json = '';

// Parameterized Query Spanning Multiple Lines
$query .= <<<EOD
SELECT 
  ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry) as geom, 
  field_1, 
  field_2, 
  field_n 
FROM
  your_data
WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(wkb_geometry, ST_GeomFromEWKT( $1 ));
EOD;

$conn = pg_pconnect('host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=dbNAME user=dbUSERNAME password=dbPASSWORD');

// Pass-in your bounds EWKT parameter..
$result = pg_query_params($conn, $query, array($ewkt));

if($result)
{
    while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $json .= '{"Feature": {';
        $json .= '"geom": "' . $row['geom'] . '",';
        $json .= '"field_1": "' . $row['field_1'] . '",';
        $json .= '"field_2": "' . $row['field_2'] . '",';
        $json .= '"field_n": "' . $row['field_n1'] . '",';
        $json .= "}}";
    }
}

echo $json;
?>
```

**JavaScript: Example method to [render GeoJSON](https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps/blob/master/GeoJSON.js)** using the 3rd-party library, mentioned above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="GeoJSON.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var featureOverlay = []; // Create an array to hold all of your features.

    // Pass your individual GeoJSON objects into a method like this.
    function renderGeoJSON(geoJSON)
    {
        var pOptions = {
          strokeColor: '#00FFFF',
          strokeOpacity: 1,
          strokeWidth: 2,
          fillColor: '#00FFFF',
          fillOpacity: 0
        };

        var featureGeoJSON = new GeoJSON(geoJSON, pOptions);

        if (featureGeoJSON.error)
        {
            alert('Errors detected in GeoJSON geometry expression.');
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i=0; i<featureGeoJSON.length; i++)
            {
                // Attach the feature to the map..
                featureGeoJSON[i].setMap(map);

                // Save a reference to the feature in your array..
                featureOverlay.push(featureGeoJSON[i]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I put this together pretty quickly, but hopefully it conveys the overall idea with a few examples/snippets demonstrating specific steps. And hopefully I didn't litter the examples with too many mistakes. FWIW, there are gotchas and caveats at each step, and likely better ways of doing at least a few of the things. So let me stress not to take this as gospel!

Comment: I really appreciate your through response. I was looking at geoserver, however there wasn't enough documentation on the subject. At least at the level I could understand. Your post already give me enough confidence to ease my mind on the fact that this functionality sohuld be possible. I am going to research the topics you posted. Thanks!

Comment: @user3032973, thanks for accepting. If you want to stay with GeoServer, you could consider [overlaying data using WMS layers](http://www.sigacts.com/html5/google-maps-api-with-wms-overlay/). If your GeoServer instance is not on the same machine serving your Google Map application, you may need to use a server-side language to perform the actual WMS request.

Comment: There isn't really enough documentation for me to digest to understant geoserver in a timly manner. I need to start developing this next week. there is also a need to send additional parameters with the information saved from the shapefile. Can I merge that with the geojson array?

Comment: PostGIS will give you a raw, GeoJSON geometry expression. So I wouldn't merge it with the GeoJSON itself (though it's possible). I'd just create a generic feature object, with a GeoJSON property, and then expand the feature object with whatever additional properties you want to include.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Map Engine? Designed for heavy geo data

https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/3342103?hl=en

Comment: The examples I was able to find which use that service are incredibly slow. Seem to be slower than server side kml files.

Comment: Looks like it could be a good viable option. I havnt found any examples with this. But does the Pro version allow you to add/remove polygons or markers? It looks like you can have up to X amount of layers. If that not feasible I wonder how much the enterprise version is.